# My location service is not working

Tags: android, service, gps, location

My application works as follows:

- I have one location listener to every activity
- My location listener(which contains location listener) send broadcast on location changed
- All activities have broadcast receiver which allows them to set location on map

It has to be working like that, but even my service doesn't start. I'm exhausted writing this app so I place my code here, maybe I overlooked some simple issue. I need help with that topic:

GPS Service:

```
// package and imports

public class GeoService extends Service {
    LocationListener GPSLocationListener, NetworkLocationListener;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    private IBinder mBinder;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        getPosition();
        return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        getPosition();
        if (mBinder == null) mBinder = new GeoBinder();
        return mBinder;
    }

    private void getPosition() {
        GPSLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                sendPosition(location);
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), provider + " is now disabled. Turn it on to find better GPS position.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), provider.toUpperCase() + " is now enabled. Waiting for better position..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                switch (status) {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, NetworkLocationListener);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        locationManager.removeUpdates(NetworkLocationListener);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        NetworkLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                sendPosition(location);
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        };

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, GPSLocationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, NetworkLocationListener);

        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && !locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) alert();
    }

    private void alert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        builder.setMessage("Internet connection and GPS are not avaiable!.").setCancelable(false).setTitle("No location provider!").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setPositiveButton("Change settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class));
            }
        }).create().show();
    }

    void sendPosition(Location location) {
        Intent gpsPosition = new Intent();
        gpsPosition.putExtra("location", location);
        gpsPosition.setAction(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        sendBroadcast(gpsPosition);
    }

    public GeoPoint getGeoPoint(final Location loc) {
        int lat = (int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1e6);
        int lon = (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1e6);
        return new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
    }

    public GeoPoint getLastLocation() {
        GeoPoint lastKnownPoint;

        Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (lastKnownLocation == null) lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (lastKnownLocation != null) lastKnownPoint = getGeoPoint(lastKnownLocation);
        else lastKnownPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (51.110582 * 1E6), (int) (17.031509 * 1E6));
        return lastKnownPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSLocationListener);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(NetworkLocationListener);
    }

    public class GeoBinder extends Binder {
        public GeoService getService() {
            return GeoService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

One of Activities: (I tried to start or bind service but none method seems to be working).

```
// package and imports

public class ShareLocationActivity extends MapActivity {
    private final int PICK_CONTACT = 123;

    MapView.LayoutParams mapMarkerParams;
    MapController mapController;
    Location lastLocation;
    ImageView mapMarker;
    GeoPoint current;
    MapView map;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection;
    GeoService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    BroadcastReceiver locationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            setPosition((Location) intent.getParcelableExtra("location"));
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_share_location);

        mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                GeoBinder binder = (GeoBinder) service;
                mService = binder.getService();
                mBound = true;

                mapController = map.getController();
                mapController.setCenter(mService.getLastLocation());
                mapController.setZoom(17);
            }

            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                mBound = false;
            }
        };

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeoService.class);
        startService(intent);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.shareMapView);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setSaveEnabled(true);

        mapMarker = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        mapMarker.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.presence_online);

        Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareActivityButton);
        share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent contacts_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(contacts_intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            }
        });

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        registerReceiver(locationReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
            case (PICK_CONTACT):
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (current != null) sendSms(data);
                    else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No GPS data yet..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!mBound) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeoService.class);
            bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        map.removeAllViews();
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        map.removeAllViews();
    }

    void setPosition(Location location) {

        map.removeAllViews();

        current = mService.getGeoPoint(location);
        mapMarkerParams = new MapView.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, current, MapView.LayoutParams.TOP_LEFT);
        map.addView(mapMarker, mapMarkerParams);
        mapController.setCenter(current);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And to be sure Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="gps.counter"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="10"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ico"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

            <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".SaveLocationActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".ShareLocationActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".RecordTrackActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" />

            <service
                android:name=".GeoService"
                android:enabled="true" />
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to keep service and activity which uses it in one package.
It is small issue but can be big problem for someone.